# Array with multiple types?

Tags: delphi, arrays, delphi-2009

I was wondering if there is a way to make an array which would have multiple types of data fields.

So far I was using `aMyArray: array of array [0..1] of TPoint;`

But now, it is not enough for me. I need to add 3 more elements to the existing 2 "Point" elements making it an array like `aMyArray: array of (TPoint,TPoint,real,real,real)`

So each element of aMyArray would have 5 'children', 2 of which are of a TPoint type and 3 of them are 'real' type.

Is this possible to implement somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe a record like

```
TMyType = record
  Points: array[0..1] of TPoint;
  Floats: array[0..2] of Real;
end;
```

or

```
TMyType = record
  Point0: TPoint;
  Point1: TPoint;
  Float0: Real;
  Float1: Real;
  Float2: Real;
end;
```

works for you.

Comment: +1. Structures with fixed numbers of elements with heterogeneous types are exactly what records are for.

Comment: A significant clue being that `TPoint` itself is a record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of Variants to store different data in each element. But array were designed to store homogenous data. If your data storage requirements are more complex, start to look for different containers.

Comment: Variants can't hold records like TPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a TStringList or decendant, with AddObject.

Comment: Really? Could you demonstrate that, please?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use variant records. For an example [see this](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa070803a.htm)